# How can I bring corners of image as half circle for each square corner?

Tags: reactjs

How can I bring corners of image as half circle (using css) for each square corner shown right side of the image. Is it even possible to achieve this using css and using single image?

[image]

```
import react from "react";

const App = () => {
return (
 <>
  <img
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80"
    alt="hello"
    width="400px"
    height='400px'
    style={{
      borderRadius: '150px 150px 150px 150px',
    }}
  />
 </>
 );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path).  There are other options using SVGs and masking.

```css
.clipped {
  clip-path: path('m374 256c93-81-37-211-118-118-81-93-211 37-118 118-93 81 37 211 118 118 81 93 211-37 118-118z');
}
```

```html
<img width=512 height=512 src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1558979158-65a1eaa08691?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" alt="Example of a clipped image" class="clipped" />
```